# Не видно ui обьектов в Canvas в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не видно ui обьектов в canvas. У меня 2 canvas, я не вижу обьектов на втором canvas они невидимые, почему так. Отображение в layers включено. Вот картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, вы на предыдущий свой вопрос не ответили, хотя обещали, сейчас вопрос неполноценен и пользы для людей не несет. Во-вторых, уже второй вопрос подряд на уровне "у меня **что-то** не работает, но вы мне как-то помогите". Невозможно без дополнительных скриншотов и всех настроек канвасов сказать, почему не работает.

Comment: Да надо ответить. Почему ничего не показал ? Вот картинка с настройками канваса. Второй канвас с такими же настройками.

Comment: Ну в данный момент компонент `Canvas` на скриншоте выключен, именно поэтому он ничего и не рисует.

Comment: Так а где он выключен ? Я не вижу.

Comment: А точно увидел, ну я с unity работаю недолго.

Comment: И на этом вопрос решен?

Comment: Да большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я был не внимателен и не поставил галочку Canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]